# phones.map is not a function REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the . map method and i am getting phones.map is not a function error .

Below is my code

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {React , useState , useEffect} from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios';
export default function Phones() {
  const [phones,setPhones] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products/search?q=phone")
    .then(res => {      
      setPhones(res.data)      
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  },[])
  const display_phones = phones.map(item => <h1> {item.name} </h1>)


  return(
  <div className="Phones">
      {display_phones}

    </div>
  
  )
}
```

Comment: please try using `phones?.map()` instead of `phones.map()`.

Comment: I expect that the `res.data` may is `undefined`, just double check.

Comment: If `phones.map` is not a function then `phones` is not an array.  So what is it?  When you debug, what value does `phones` have when this error occurs?  What value do you expect it to have?  Why?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-keller-z2gy32?file=/src/screens/Phones.js -- ive tried no work

Comment: res.data is saving undefined or null into phones. You should add a backup like this  setPhones(res.data || []).

Comment: useState([]) is an array so i am expecting setPhones to set it it an array no?

Comment: @lb2020: That would be true if your code never *changes* that state value.  If you carefully examine all of the code you've provided, can you find *anywhere* in that code where you update that state value at all?

Comment: I dont update i set it once in the useEffect by setPhones(res.data) .

Comment: @lb2020: So you don't change the state value, but instead you change the state value?  You seem confused on what your code is doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you get an object that has an array of products and you already have to map it.

```
{products: Array(4), total: 4, skip: 0, limit: 4}
```

Try the following:

```
const display_phones = phones.products.map(item => <h1> {item.title} </h1>)
```

FYI Your object does not have a key like a name

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the state value for `phones` to an empty array:

```
const [phones,setPhones] = useState([])
```

So on the first render you can successfully `.map()` over that array.  But later you update that state value:

```
setPhones(res.data)
```

Clearly whatever you update it to is *not* an array.  So what is it?  This is the URL you're accessing to fetch data:

```
https://dummyjson.com/products/search?q=phone
```

So let's make a request there and see what it returns...

```
{
   "products":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "title":"iPhone 9",
         "description":"An apple mobile which is nothing like apple",
         "price":549,
         "discountPercentage":12.96,
         "rating":4.69,
         "stock":94,
         "brand":"Apple",
         "category":"smartphones",
         "thumbnail":"https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/thumbnail.jpg",
         "images":[
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/1.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/2.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/3.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/4.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/thumbnail.jpg"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "title":"iPhone X",
         "description":"SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super Retina HD display with OLED technology A12 Bionic chip with ...",
         "price":899,
         "discountPercentage":17.94,
         "rating":4.44,
         "stock":34,
         "brand":"Apple",
         "category":"smartphones",
         "thumbnail":"https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/thumbnail.jpg",
         "images":[
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/1.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/2.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/3.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/thumbnail.jpg"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":71,
         "title":"Women Shoulder Bags",
         "description":"LouisWill Women Shoulder Bags Long Clutches Cross Body Bags Phone Bags PU Leather Hand Bags Large Capacity Card Holders Zipper Coin Purses Fashion Crossbody Bags for Girls Ladies",
         "price":46,
         "discountPercentage":14.65,
         "rating":4.71,
         "stock":17,
         "brand":"LouisWill",
         "category":"womens-bags",
         "thumbnail":"https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/71/thumbnail.jpg",
         "images":[
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/71/1.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/71/2.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/71/3.webp",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/71/thumbnail.jpg"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":86,
         "title":"Bluetooth Aux",
         "description":"Bluetooth Aux Bluetooth Car Aux Car Bluetooth Transmitter Aux Audio Receiver Handfree Car Bluetooth Music Receiver Universal 3.5mm Streaming A2DP Wireless Auto AUX Audio Adapter With Mic For Phone MP3",
         "price":25,
         "discountPercentage":10.56,
         "rating":4.57,
         "stock":22,
         "brand":"Car Aux",
         "category":"automotive",
         "thumbnail":"https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/86/thumbnail.jpg",
         "images":[
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/86/1.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/86/2.webp",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/86/3.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/86/4.jpg",
            "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/86/thumbnail.jpg"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "total":4,
   "skip":0,
   "limit":4
}
```

If that's the contents of the response (which is `res` in your code), then what do you expect `res.data` to be and why?

*If* the error was telling you that `phones` is `undefined` then we could conclude that `res` is probably this entire object and `data` isn't a property on this object, so you'd be setting state to `undefined`.  *But* the error is specifically telling us that `.map()` is not a function.  Which means `res.data` is *something*, and likely an object.

It seems that `res.data` is this entire object.  So you're probably looking for the `products` property on this object:

```
setPhones(res.data.products)
```

Comment: I was expecting res.data to give me a array of objects but once i took a look at what the fetch was getting it was getting objects , the data i was looking for was inside the products array . res.data returns everything wheras setPhones(res.data.products) worked for me